# SSIS with Sql Server 2005 express

Tags: ssis, sql-server-express

Can we use SSIS with SQL Server (2005) Express as database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Express editions don't come with SSIS package. Please check this http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx

One way to get around it is to build SSIS packages on Standard Edition and copy them. Here, this might be handy http://daron.yondem.com/PermaLink.aspx?guid=c44d040b-ed02-4330-a662-4cd9d6fb1bf3

cheers

Comment: Understand with first link description,In the Second link description they said Develop SSIS package in Standard/Enterprise edition and can be schedule in Express edition,have furhter dought regarding the same SSIS package can point(do ETL operations on) to Express database, Thanks.