# Installing SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have Sql server 2008 R2 Express edition setup with me.
IS it possible to install Sql Server Integration Services with this setup?

If no, how do I install SSIS? Is it licensed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssis%5D+express

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS with Sql Server 2005 express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046888/ssis-with-sql-server-2005-express)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS with Sql Server 2005 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046888/ssis-with-sql-server-2005-express)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SSIS** is licensed - there is no free version. You need Developer, Standard, or Enterprise license. See [MSDN for SSIS feature reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx#SSIS).

Answer (score 2):

you can use developer edition if you want to learn only. The only limitation or difference from Enterprise to Developer is the license. You cannot use Developer in an environment other than development or you are violating your license agreement. Otherwise this functions exactly as Enterprise Edition.